# Autocomplete filename in script

Tags: scripts, auto-completion

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for a while. I am trying to find a way to use autocomplete for more than just commands, eg: for files inside the current folder.

One possible use case (but not the only one): copy file 1.txt into a directory inside the current one called i* (I know there's only one). Command line, it would be:

```
cp 1.txt i[TAB]
```

Is there any way I can do this in a script?

Comment: If you're certain there's only one such file, `cp 1.txt i*` should work fine. Be warned that multiple files would screw this up.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    find . -name "i*" -type d -exec cp 1.txt {} \;
```

This command recursively descend the directory form current directory and search files whose name begins with letter `i`. Option `-type d` restricts the search to directory.

Than perform `cp` command and copy `1.txt` in each file (directory) found.

In order to limit `find` to current directory you should use `-maxdepth` option:

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -name "i*" -type d -exec cp 1.txt {} \;
```

You can use muru's tip and use `cp 1.txt i*` but this fails in case of multiple `i*` file, while `find` command executes `cp` command multiple times and this can be a problem too.

So you should choose one or the other depending on the case and what you need.